# How can you change the case of a backreference in Ex-mode substitute command?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, ex-mode, letter-case

For instance, let's say I want to change all instances of `Ctrl-m`, `Ctrl-p`, etc., in a document to the more conventional `^M`, `^P`, etc.  I can use `:s/Ctrl-\(.\)/^\1`to *almost* accomplish this, but it leaves the letters in lowercase where they should be in uppercase.

How can I change the case of a backreferenced regex match in a Ex-mode substitute command?  (`:s`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
:%s/Ctrl-\(.\)/^\u\1/g
```

For more information: [`:help s/\u`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#s%2F%5Cu).